# Need an xslt transformation which refer to another xml

Tags: xml, xslt

Required Stylesheet should refer the refer.xml and must get only the values of that elements from the input.xml. How to do that

**Input.xml** which is the request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Virgin records</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1990</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Eros</title>
    <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>BMG</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1997</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>One night only</title>
    <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1998</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Romanza</title>
    <artist>Andrea Bocelli</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>10.80</price>
    <year>1996</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>When a man loves a woman</title>
    <artist>Percy Sledge</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Atlantic</company>
    <price>8.70</price>
    <year>1987</year>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

**refer.xml** - here we will have our elements from the input

```
<catalog>
<cd>
    <country name="USA">
    <title>When a man loves a woman</title>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    </country>
    <country name="UK">
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <title>One night only</title>
    </country>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

**Output.xml** - This shows the values of elements which are shown in refer.xml

```
<country name="USA">
<cd>
    <title>When a man loves a woman</title>
    <price>8.70</price>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <price>9.90</price>
</cd>
</country>
<country name="UK">
<cd>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <price>10.20</price>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>One night only</title>
    <price>10.90</price>
</cd>
</country>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`document` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-document) in your XSLT to look up values from a different XML file from the one you are transforming.

Comment: how exactly i use that. could you post the stylesheet for my example

Comment: Post your best shot at a stylesheet that converts refer.xml into output.xml. If you can't work out how to look up the prices, we can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your intention right, but for your example I came up with the following:
The idea is, to get in your refer.xml and get your title of your cd. Then you open the input.xml and search for your matching title in there. My code does not check if the found CD is from the correct country but this change is easily done.

### XSL-FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <catalog>
            <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd/country/@name">
                <country>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:for-each select="../title">
                        <xsl:variable name="reftitle" select="."/>
                        <xsl:for-each select="document('input.xml')/catalog/cd">
                            <xsl:variable name="title" select="title"/>     
                            <xsl:variable name="price" select="price"/>


                            <xsl:if test="$reftitle=$title">
                            <cd>
                                <title>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$reftitle"/>
                                </title>
                                <price>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$price"/>
                                </price>
                            </cd>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </country>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </catalog>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this creates your desired output. I dunno if the three nested loops are nessecary, or if there is a cleaner version to do it, but it'll give you a start.